# Strange behavior of NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration, syntax, piecewise

I have some function f[x,y,a], where a is some parameter, defined as piecewise

```
f[x,y,a] = Piecewise[{{g[x,y,a], a<m[x]}, {0, True}}]
```

Here $m$ is some function. I need to integrate the function f with some weight h[x] over the two-dimensional domain `{x, x1,x2},` `{y, y1, v[x])}`, where `x1,x2,y1` are the ordinary numbers and `v[x]` is some given function. Precisely, I want to obtain the table of integral values for varying parameter `a` from `a1` to `a2` with the step `da`:

```
TableNeutral = Table[{a, Re[NIntegrate[h[x]f[x,y,a], {x, x1, x2},{y, y1, v[x]},Evaluated-> False]]}, {a, a1, a2, da}]
```

Surprisingly, when generating the table Mathematica writes:

> The integrand ... has evaluated to non-numerical values for all
>   sampling points in the region with boundaries $\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$

Moreover, the generated table contains the numerical values for some domain of the values $a$, while for some values of $a$ it just writes the code (see the picture):
[image]

At the picture the role of parameter `a` is played by $m\chi$, the role of `f[...]` is played by `CS1totalxscalar[...]`, the role of `y` is played by `s2`, and the role of `g[...]` is played by `PhotonDFapprox[...]`.

What can be a reason for this, and how to correct this?

My code:

```
(*Not relevant*)
coef0 = g\[Chi]s*Sqrt[4*Pi*\[Alpha]]*gps

(*Pre-definition of the function f*)
CS1scalar[Ss_, s2_, m\[Chi]_, mp_]= ((4 m\[Chi]^2-s2) Sqrt[s2 (s2-4 m\[Chi]^2)] (Sqrt[mp^4-2 mp^2 (s2+Ss)+(s2-Ss)^2] (mp^6-mp^4 (s2+5 Ss)+mp^2 Ss (2 s2-25 Ss)+Ss^2 (7 s2-3 Ss))-2 Ss^2 (9 mp^4+mp^2 (6 Ss-10 s2)+2 s2^2-2 s2 Ss+Ss^2) Log[(mp^2-Sqrt[mp^4-2 mp^2 (s2+Ss)+(s2-Ss)^2]-s2+Ss)/(mp^2+Sqrt[mp^4-2 mp^2 (s2+Ss)+(s2-Ss)^2]-s2+Ss)] ))/(256 \[Pi]^3 s2^3 Ss^2 (mp^2-Ss)^3)

(*Definition of the function g*)
v[x_, mp_, EN_] = x*EN/(mp + x*EN);
gamma[x_, mp_, EN_] = 1/Sqrt[1 - v[x, mp, EN]^2];
ECM[x_, mp_, EN_] = 
 FullSimplify[
  x*EN*(1 - v[x, mp, EN])*gamma[x, mp, EN] + 
   Sqrt[mp^2 + (x*EN*(1 - v[x, mp, EN])*gamma[x, mp, EN])^2], 
  Assumptions -> mp > 0 && EN > 0 && x > 0] 
PhotonDFfullapprox[x_, Z_, \[Alpha]_, mN_, qperp_, R_, S_] = 
  Assuming[mN > 0 && x > 0, 
   3*\[Alpha]*Z^2/(4*Pi)*((1 + (1 - x)^2)/x)*
    qperp^2/(qperp^2 + x^2*mN^2)^2*
    SphericalBesselJ[1, R*Sqrt[(x*mN)^2 + qperp^2]]/(R*x*mN)*
    Exp[-x^2*mN^2*S^2]];
PhotonDFapprox[x_, Z_, \[Alpha]_, mN_, R_, S_] = 
  Integrate[
   PhotonDFfullapprox[x, Z, \[Alpha], mN, qperp, R, S]*2*
    qperp, {qperp, 0, Sqrt[(4.49/5)^2 - x^2*mN^2]}];

(*Definition of the function f*)
CS1totalscalar[x_, s2_, m\[Chi]_, mp_, \[Alpha]_, g\[Chi]s_, gps_] = 
  coef0^2*CS1scalar[Ss, s2, m\[Chi], mp] /. 
   Ss -> ECM[x, 0.938, 3.6*10^4]^2 ;
CS1totalxscalar[x_, s2_, m\[Chi]_, mp_, \[Alpha]_, g\[Chi]s_, 
   gps_] =  
  Piecewise[{{CS1totalscalar[x, s2, m\[Chi], mp, \[Alpha], g\[Chi]s, 
      gps], m\[Chi] <= (ECM[x, 0.938, 3.6*10^4] - 0.938)/2}, {0, 
     m\[Chi] > (ECM[x, 0.938, 3.6*10^4] - 0.938)/2}}];
(Sqrt[2*0.938*3.6*10^4*10^-2 + 0.938^2] - 0.938)/2

(*Table*)

Tablescalar = 
 Table[{m\[Chi], 
   Re[NIntegrate[
     CS1totalxscalar[x, s2, m\[Chi], 0.938, 1/137, 1, 0.1*0.938/240]*
      PhotonDFapprox[x, 42, 1/137, 90, 5, 0.726], {x, 10^-7, 
      4.49/(5*90)}, {s2, 
      4*m\[Chi]^2, (ECM[x, 0.938, 3.6*10^4] - 0.938)^2}, 
     Evaluated -> False]]}, {m\[Chi], 0.001, 12.5, 0.1}]
```

Comment: Can you give us some working code that shows the problem? The f and Table you have presented have many undefined parameters and functions.

Comment: @bills : I've added the code. I hope that it is more or less understandable.

Comment: I fixed `CS1totalxscalar`  and `PhotonDFapprox` to take only numeric `s2` and `x` and it works. (There is no `Evaluated->False` in my version 10.1 so I deleted that )  I do get some slow convergence warnings but with reasonable looking numeric results returned.

Comment: @george2079 : sorry. but how did you do that?

Comment: for the two functions called directly by `NIntegrate` do like: `CS1totalxscalar[x_?NumericQ, s2_?NumericQ, m\[Chi]_, mp_, \[Alpha]_, 
  g\[Chi]s_, gps_] = ..`   (restart your kernel to clear old definitions).  I thought `Evaluated->False` eliminated the need for that but as I say I cant test it.